# Twitter Bootstrap Overflowing

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Example](http://silverfishdevelopment.com/maaco)

This isn't working like they have in the examples on the Bootstrap page. The header keeps overflowing the page unless I give it a BIG margin-top. Am I doing something wrong? I'd really like to be able to use Bootstrap. It would certainly save me a boat load of time.

Comment: Start it from the scratch. Get a working example and iteratively modify it step-by-step to get what you need. This is what every one of us does when not experienced enough to get it worked in a moment

Comment: So you decided to ignore my answer and just accept the one that came after it with the same content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `line-height: 20px;` in the `body` code is restricting the header area from expanding to the size of the font. Adding `line-height: 100px;` (same as font-size) or `line-height: 100%;` to the `header` code should give you desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could wrap your "Maaco status check" in a <h1> tag, and forgo your custom styling.

Comment: I realize this was downvoted, but I still hold this is likely a better approach than the one he was using.  He said he wanted to use bootstrap, but then didn't use the built-in styles (nor override them), and your header elements should be inside h tags.  Especially for proper SEO and assistive technologies (screen readers).